# Autocomplete is not working and no dropdownlist appears

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using the script written below for autocomplete. It is working when I add jquery-1.8.3.js in my master page, but when I remove it from master page and add it to the specific page, it stops working. I don't know why it is causing this problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            $(function () {
                $(".tb").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "AutoInsuranceCompanyList.asmx/FetchCompanyList",
                            data: "{ 'cmp': '" + request.term + "' }",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        value: item.INSCO
                                    }
                                }))
                            },
                            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert(textStatus);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength: 1
                });
            });
        }
    </script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" UpdateMode="Conditional" Visible="true" RenderMode="Inline"runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
                    <ul class="formList">
                        <li class="clear">
                            <label>
                                Insurance Company:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsuranceCompany" class="tb" runat="server"                               MaxLength="40"></asp:TextBox>
                             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator33" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtInsuranceCompany" ErrorMessage="Please enter insurance company name" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </li>
                     </ul> 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

At runtime in browser it shows

```
<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtInsuranceCompany" class="tb ac_input" type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="40" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtInsuranceCompany">
```

Please help

Comment: Why you want to remove from MasterPage?

Comment: What happens in the console window?

Comment: Simple Guess.. It wont work without any jquery lib reference... So at least it should be in .aspx or .master

Comment: When I add jquery-1.8.3.js in master it affects some other jquery functions. I removed it from master page and placed it inside my aspx page. but when I do so my autocomplete stops working.

Comment: In console no error is showing

Comment: when I place jquery-1.8.3.js in my master page and run it, it works fine and in browser it shows

    <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtInsuranceCompany" class="tb ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" maxlength="40" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtInsuranceCompany" autocomplete="off">
 
I don't understand why it is not working when I place jquery-1.8.3.js in aspx file while in master page it is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var availableTags = Array();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "AutoInsuranceCompanyList.asmx/FetchCompanyList",
            data: "{ 'cmp': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                $.map(data.d, function (item) {

                    availableTags.push(item.INSCO);

                })
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
        jQuery(".tb").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    })



</script>
```

Comment: autocomplete Jquery Library is added?

Comment: Yes I added it in my master page

Answer (score 0):

when I place jquery-1.8.3.js in my master page and run it, it works fine and in browser it shows

```
<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtInsuranceCompany" class="tb ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" maxlength="40" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtInsuranceCompany" autocomplete="off">
```

I don't understand why it is not working when I place jquery-1.8.3.js in aspx file while in master page it is working correctly

I placed my jquery in the content section of aspx page and it worked. Thanks for your efforts and replies friends.